# Python multiprocessing(Pool) error

Tags: python, python-3.x, multitasking

Tengo un problema con el multiprocesado de mi programa. Este es el codigo del programa y debajo inserto el error:

Programa:

```
import argparse
import sys
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--x", type=float, default=1.0)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sys.stdout.write(str(numeroprimo()))

num = input("Inserte un numero: ")


def numeroprimo():
    if int(num) > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(num)):
            if (int(num) % i) == 0:
                print(num, "no es un numero primo")
                break
        else:
            print(num, "es un numero primo")
    else:
        print(num, "no es un numero primo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    t1 = time.time()
    for x in range(1):
        p = Pool()
        p.map(numeroprimo(), num)
        p.close()
        p.join()
    print("Tomó:", time.time()-t1)
```

Error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.    py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File     "C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.    py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Prime number checker.py", line 33, in <module>
    p.map(primenumber(), num)
  File     "C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.    py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File     "C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.    py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

En la línea:

```
p.map(numeroprimo(), num)
```

Por un lado, con los paréntesis `()` estás usando el valor devuelto por la función `numeroprimo`, cuyo valor por defecto es `None` por no indicar explícitamente nada mediante un `return`. Ese es el error que te da.

Por otro lado, la función no usa argumentos, por lo que de nada sirve pasarle la variable `num`. Tendrás suerte de que la pille por ser variable global.

Pero en el caso de que `numeroprimo` aceptara argumentos, a `Pool.map` tienes que pasarle un *iterador* como segundo argumento, algo así: `[num]`

Reinterpretando lo que quieres hacer, el código podía ser algo así:

```
def numeroprimo(n):
    res = n > 1 and all(n%i != 0 for i in range(2,n))
    print("{:6d}".format(n), "sí" if res else "no", "es número primo")
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #main()
    num = input("Inserte un numero: ")
    t1 = time.time()
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(numeroprimo, range(2, int(num)))
    print("Tomó:", time.time()-t1)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @SantiagoPardal recuerda marcar la respuesta de Chema como buena :)

Comment: La marque, pero no me lo saca, nose por que :(